Uploading file by s3 graphql types issues
I have this function in my nestJs app to upload file:
async  uploadImageObject(file:FileUpload,bucketName:string): Promise<void> {

    const { createReadStream, filename,mimetype, encoding } = file;
    console.log("uploading...");

    
      const isExist = await this.isBucketExist(bucketName)
      if (!isExist ) {
        await this.createBucket(bucketName)
      }

      const multiPartParams = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: filename,
        Body:createReadStream()
      };

      // Create a multipart upload
      console.log('Creating multipart upload for:', filename);
      const createMultipartUploadResponse = await this.s3.send(new PutObjectCommand(multiPartParams));
      console.log(createMultipartUploadResponse);
    
      
    }


and this is the mutation triggers it:
  @Mutation(() => Boolean, { name: 'uploadImage' })
  async uploadImage(
    @Args({ name: 'file', type: () => GraphQLUpload })
    file: Promise<FileUpload>,
    @Args('bucketName') bucketName: string,
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      console.log('upload triggered, here is the file:', file, bucketName);
      const uploaded = await file;
      await this.cloudService.uploadImageObject(uploaded, bucketName);
      return true; // Upload successful
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
      return false; // Upload failed
    }
  }


and my backend is running successfully without any error.
But when i want to upload a file in my frontend(NextJs) by below function:
 const [UploadToAWS, { loading }] = useMutation(UPLOAD);

  async function uploadToAWS(image: File, bucketName: string) {

    try {
      await UploadToAWS({ variables: {file:image, bucketName } });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      
    }
  }

It does not send the file. But it sends the bucketName.
Seems that it is because there is a mismatch between types of File' (in frontend) and Promise` in backend mutation. but I'm not sure and I do not what to do
All i want is upload a file. Frontend is nextJs(graphql) and the backend NestJs.
I don't know whether I have to change my backend functionalities or frontend.
